# How to predict Time to Failure

Tags: regression, time-series, survival

I have a data set that contain only two columns , first is independent variable which is sensor measurements and the other column is the target which is time to failure in any time unit.
[image]
The problem states that the data are time series , while i know that in time series the index of the data is the time in days or months or years.

I thought in survival analysis , and simple linear regression , but I don't know if either approaches can help me to solve this problem ?

So, How can I think for a solution for this problem

Answer (score 1):

I found that making scatterplots of the data was informative. First, here is a plot of Time To Failure versus Sensor Reading:

[image]

You can see that there is no visually apparent strong relationship between the two variables.

Here is a plot of Index versus Time To Failure and you can see from the last two digits in the data you posted, as index increases the time to failure decreases. I would normally expect older parts to have a shorter remaining time to failure, so index (representing time in service) appears to strongly predict time to failure.

[image]

Comment: but in the question , it was required to use rmse for assessment ?

Comment: RMSE is similar to "average size of regression error", so if you fit a straight line to the data in each scatterplot the RMSE using index (time) would be *very* much smaller than the RMSE using sensor readings.

Comment: Ok , I got informed , thank you !